# Unable to get coffescript running, making a <div> class into a link

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

So i am actually following a ruby on rail introductory video tutorial...
This part of the course was about to teach me some coffeescript

So the plan is to make this grey container of the  follow the same link as my "view answers"

[image: the sample site]

the code i am using is as below. i am also told that since i am using turbolinks i should include the "(document).on "page:load", ready" line

*"home.coffee"*

```
ready = ->
$(".media").on "click", -> 
     (document).location = $(this).data("target")
     return false

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on "page:load", ready
```

However, after testing it out. Clicking on the grey container, does nothing.
Am i missing some sort of script for this to work? Earlier i tested out Console.log("TEST") on the coffee script , and it was able to print out on chrome's inspect .

**Current layout of my pages**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>PROJECT HU</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>


  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.3" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>

<body>
    <%= render 'home/navbar' %>

    <%= yield %> <!-- yield is content of the html-->
    <%= render 'home/new_question_form' %>

</body>

</html>
```

**Index Page as below**
based on my tutorial, i had to add this 
data-target="<%= question_path(q) %>" into the media

```
<div class = "well">
    <h1>WELCOME LA</h1>
</div>
<div class='container'>
<!--#loop this html as much as number of question in the database-->
    <div class="boxes">
        <% @questions.each do |q|%> 
            <div class="media" data-target="<%= question_path(q) %>">
                    <div class="media-left">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="media-object" src="<%= q.gravatar%>" alt="sampleImg">

                    </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading"><%= q.email%> asked : </h4>
                        <div class="time"><%= time_ago_in_words q.created_at%></div>
                        <%= q.body %>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <a href= "<%= question_path(q)%>" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">View Answers</a>
                    </div>
            </div>
        <%end%>
    </div>
    <% if @questions.empty? %>
        <div class="alert alert-info">Ooops.... There's no questions here.</div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at your coffeescript, there are a few things wrong:

```
ready = ->
$(".media").on "click", -> 
     (document).location = $(this).data("target")
     return false

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on "page:load", ready
```

1. Line 2 should be indented
2. There's no need to wrap `document` in parentheses; were you trying to wrap it in a jQuery object?
3. In CoffeeScript, you can just put `false` on the last line of a function or closure and it'll be returned

Assuming your indentation is right, and `.media` has a `data-target` attribute, you might want to validate that your click handler is being triggered. The quick-hack way of doing that is dropping in a quick `console.log` call in there, but you can also use the debugger to create a breakpoint (which is more powerful). I'd start by ensuring:

1. `$(".media")` matches something you expect
2. Your `ready` closure is being called on click
3. `$(this).data("target")` returns the value you're expecting

If number 2 isn't happening, you can start looking at your `page:load` binding; maybe Turbolinks hasn't been loaded, or you're not using the current version?

Note: You don't want to bind to both `ready` and `page:load` or you'll have two click handlers registered. In the latest TurboLinks, `page:load` will handle both page load and TurboLinks navigation appropriately.

Comment: oh my..... so its because i did not indent it , the code was not working...
thanks for the other tips as well , it would most definitely help me out next time! Thanks!

Comment: if you guy's don't mind helping out again..
here's another link to my woes ...                                                                 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41787739/unable-to-make-auto-focus-on-fields-for-bootstrap-modal

Answer (score 2):

If this is your real indentation:

```
ready = ->
$(".media").on "click", -> 
     (document).location = $(this).data("target")
     return false
```

then your `ready` function is empty. The JavaScript version of that is (more or less) like this:

```
var ready = function() { };
$(".media").on("click", function() {
     (document).location = $(this).data("target")
     return false
});
```

Your indentation defines the block structure of your CoffeeScript code so you must get it right:

```
ready = ->
  $('.media').on 'click', -> 
    document.location = $(@).data('target')
    false
```

Also, CoffeeScript functions return the value of their last expression (just like in Ruby) so `return false` can be just `false` when it is the last line of the the function.

Comment: thank you so much for this explanation of how it's being translated out. it gave me a clearer view of whats happening.